# ASP.NET Web Forms Scaffolding feature missing in VS 2013 RC

Tags: asp.net, webforms, scaffolding, visual-studio-2013

The **ASP.NET Web Forms Scaffolding** feature seems to be **silently dropped from Visual Studio 2013 RC**. In the latest VS 2013 (as of September 2013) the feature [Add] -> [Scaffold] -> [Web Forms pages with read/write actions, using Entity Framework] is just missing. Microsoft didn't release any official information about this change and silently removed the documentation of the Web Forms Scaffolding feature in Visual Studio.

Also at the official ASP.NET Web site the "Web Forms Scaffolding" documentation is now missing: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/aspnet-scaffolding-with-web-forms. The page is just deleted. Its old version is still available at archive.org: http://web.archive.org/web/20130901172338/http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/aspnet-scaffolding-with-web-forms.

Does anyone know what is going to happen with ASP.NET Web Form Scaffolding? Shall we have it in VS 2013? Or it will be available ad add-on from Visual Studio Gallery or as package from NuGet?

I checked these resources and all of them seems too old:
 - http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.WebForms/ - no changes from Feb 2013, still the Web Forms scaffold feature is missing
 - http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bd1260d4-f46c-40af-aec1-e6460e6d5d7d - does not support VS 2013

Seems like Scott Hanselman also stays silent at his blog about the dropped Web Forms Scaffolding feature in VS 2013 RC: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DownloadVisualStudio2013WhileYourFeedbackStillMatters.aspx

Does anyone know how to run ASP.NET Web Forms Scaffolding in Visual Studio 2013?

Svetlin Nakov

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this feature is currently dropped but Microsoft promises that it will be included in a future release.

Look at this page that was created earlier today: http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/release-notes-%28release-candidate%29#scaffold

> Visual Studio 2013 does not currently support generating pages for a Web Forms project, but you can still use scaffolding with Web Forms by adding MVC dependencies to the project. Support for generating pages for Web Forms will be added in a future update.

Another source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/09/09/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-for-visual-studio-2013-rc.aspx says:

> We removed WebForm Scaffolding from this release. We’ll reconsider it in future releases.

Comment: Microsoft have a contradiction in two consecutive sentences in their release notes: "_With Visual Studio 2013, you can now use scaffolding for any ASP.NET project, including Web Forms. Visual Studio 2013 does not currently support generating pages for a Web Forms project, but you can still use scaffolding with Web Forms by adding MVC dependencies to the project. Support for generating pages for Web Forms will be added in a future update._"

Comment: So much for the big fat lie of "We will continue to support Web Forms". I need to use Web Forms Scaffolding with VS 2015 and am basically dead in the water.

Answer (score 1):

here it is, http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a6c3614f-83be-4749-afbc-8da394b6ea86

and the explanation here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/05/13/improvements-to-asp-net-web-forms.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage