# ASP.NET Webforms CRUD scaffolding with Entity Framework 5

Tags: webforms, entity-framework-5, scaffolding

Back in Feb MS introduced:

- http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.WebForms/
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/02/20/pre-release-of-asp-net-scaffolding-with-a-web-forms-scaffold-generator.aspx

but it appears that it will be dropped from VS2013

- [ASP.NET Web Forms Scaffolding feature missing in VS 2013 RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18703304/asp-net-web-forms-scaffolding-feature-missing-in-vs-2013-rc)

I followed the instructions here

- http://dotnetguts.blogspot.com.au/2013/06/scaffolding-for-aspnet-webforms.html

to install the package under Visual Studio 2012 but when I go to add a scaffold the scaffold generator drop down is empty.

So my question is has anyone come across a free ASP.NET Webforms scaffolding solution that can be used with Entity Framework 5?

Comment: Anyone got anything here?

Answer (score 0):

here it is, http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a6c3614f-83be-4749-afbc-8da394b6ea86

and the explanation here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/05/13/improvements-to-asp-net-web-forms.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage