# Web Forms with Scaffolding and EF 6.0

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, webforms, entity-framework-6, scaffolding

I have created a Web Forms 4.5 Web Application with individual User Accounts using Identity. I want to use scaffolding and attempted to install [Web Forms Scaffolding](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SWalther.WebFormsScaffolding) only to get the following error:

```
      Unable to find a version of 'EntityFramework' that is compatible with
     'Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.WebForms 0.1.0-pre constraint: EntityFramework 
     (>= 5.0.0 && < 6.0.0)'
```

EF 6.0 is installed by default with the template. Apparently it seems only compatible with EF 5.0. If I revert my project to use this version of EF, what will I lose? I intend to use a code-first approach. Will reverting to EF 6.0 affect the existing authentication functionality? Can anyone suggest a way to get Web Forms Scaffolding working with EF 6.0?

Apparently there are [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19174833/asp-net-webforms-crud-scaffolding-with-entity-framework-5) with EF 5 also?

Comment: Did you find any supporting package yet?

Comment: No, but I have just contacted the author to ask him about this issue.

Comment: This may be a solution - I haven't tried it yet. See Luis Molena's answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19174833/asp-net-webforms-crud-scaffolding-with-entity-framework-5

Comment: It supports VS 2013, looks not updated since 2014. I ended up using WEB API 2.